# How to insert Table of Contents in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, table-of-contents

What is the best way to insert a table of contents in Word 2010?

When I do it via *References* I get strange results: the page numbers are on the left hand side when they are meant to be on the right.  How can I get the same results that I got in earlier versions of Word such as 2003?

Comment: The default TOC formatting is based on your default template. Try other styles on [this list](http://imgur.com/3U5NEA9), if others work, then there's something wrong with your default template.

Answer (score 0):

Word 2010 is not really any different in this respect to previous versions. Yes, you should insert it in the usual way as you've suggested.

It sounds like something has messed up the styles for the TOC entries.

Have you tried closing Word, deleting the normal.dot (just move it out of it's normal folder if you want to keep it for later), restart Word and create a new blank document. The create some text with appropriate heading styles and finally insert a TOC. Does the problem still occur? Have you tried some of the other TOC styles?

Comment: This post doesn't really answer the question, and should be posted as a comment.

Comment: Really too long for a comment @TFM though in general I agree with you. I'll happily update the answer as CJ7 updates us on the questions.